# how to echo/display the custom field value in specific custom field name?

Tags: post-meta, get-the-id

I have tried this code:

> ```
> <?php query_posts(array(
>             'meta_key' => 'custom_cat',
>             'meta_value' => 'creative',
>             'post_type' => 'page'
>         ));
>             echo '<ul class="clearfix row">';
>             if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
>                     echo '<li class="col-md-4">';               
>                         the_title();
>                         the_content();
>                     echo '<i class="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "fa_icon", true ).'"></i>';
>                     echo '</li>';               
>              endwhile;  
>             echo '</ul>';
>             wp_reset_query(); ?>
> ```

to display the custom field value as a class name, but the value is not displaying. Please help me find the problem or solution to display the custom field value as class name.
I'm having hard time to debug this codes because i'm not a programmer, i'm a designer, still in the process of exploring wordpress.

Comment: Is this a custom loop you're trying to set up in a template? And you want a custom field from each of those posts to apply as a class, once again, for each post?

Comment: yes a custom loop and wanted to use custom field value of fa_icon meta key to be set as class name of an element

Comment: this code echo '<i class="'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "fa_icon", true ).'"></i>'; only displays <i class=""></i> no class value

Comment: For troubleshooting, try running var_dump() on get_the_ID to see if you're getting anything. Also try echo get_post_meta outside of the li to see if anything shows up, also if you manually put an id and it works, then it's the get_the_ID giving you trouble. I think what may fix it is replacing get_the_ID with $post->ID instead.